# rename all files within a directory and its subdirectories with batch script

Tags: command-line, batch, cmd.exe, script, rename

I would like to rename the name and the extension of all files which are located in the a certain directories and its subdirectories to a random combination of 25 alphamuneric signs (letters and figures) which is equal to the filename. The fileextension should be ".TEST"

I have found the following script which only renames in a parent directory and the it only changes the name to a random integer.

```
@ echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in ("%userprofile%\music\*.*") do (
    ren "%%~F" "!RANDOM!.test"
)
endlocal
```

So how to do it with all child directories and the combination of letters and numbers?

Comment: Apologies, edited your question rather than my answer. all should be back as it was now.

Comment: which is equal to the filename, does that mean that when you have a file called "my file.ext it should have the same number of random characteres? 7al4asc.test

Comment: I want that the file "hello.txt" becomes renamed into an combination of random small and capital letters and numbers. The amount of the digits is equal to 100.

Answer (score 0):

put /R after the word `for` so it recurses into subdirectories

```
@ echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R "%userprofile%\music\" %%F in (*.*) do (
    ren "%%~fF" "%%~fF%RANDOM%.test"
)
endlocal
```

see more details on the recursive for loop here: https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html

for Random number generation, enclose the RANDOM in % signs like `%RANDOM%`. https://riptutorial.com/batch-file/example/32511/random-numbers

if you want to put a dot between the original file name and the new extension, try `ren "%%~fF" "%%~F.%RANDOM%.test"`. on my system it formats names like `Textures\Interface\VUI+\solid_black.dds.230.test`

for powershell I'd do something like (**this is a dryrun; remove -WhatIf from the line when you are satisfied it works and want to actually execute the rename**)

`Get-ChildItem  $env:USERPROFILE\music\ -Recurse -File | Rename-Item -WhatIf -NewName { $_.Name + "." + (Get-Random -Maximum 1000)+ ".test"}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer Frank Thomas, but your adjusted script does not work on my PC.  Could there be a mistake?

Comment: generally `in` is used to filter files in the current working directory, rather than to specify the full path. try it again now.

Comment: So you mean:             ...........  for /R %%F in .....                                                                                   and over setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion I write:       cd %userprofile%\music

Comment: I tried it again but now it only takes one file of the parent folder and calls it !RANDOM!.test, but I want the filename be a random number

Comment: Still does not work and I do not know why. Could you tell me how to do it with a powershell script without admin rights?

Comment: also found the issue with the ren command in the batch. it should work now, but I do recommend echoing out the line to make sure everything evaluates correctly once before running it for real.

Comment: It´s a pity that the powershell script does not work either :( Could you comment down below the final batch script one last time that it will finally work? Please?

Comment: I've been updating my answer as I go. it contains the latest versions of both scripts. did you remove -whatif from the powershell sequence?

Comment: The powershell script says:                                                                + CategoryInfo       :InvalidArgument:                                            +FullyQualifiedErrorId: ScriptBlockArgumentInvocationFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand